# Do I need to create different models for my application and rest responses?

Tags: android, data-structures, models, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit 2 to fetch data from the web api. Now I have a structure like below:

```
-app
|-model
  |-User.java
|-network
  |-model
    |-ApiUser.java
  |-service
|-presenter
|-view
```

The retrofit converts the response to the ApiUser object. And I created a mapper to map ApiUser to the User object. I thought I should use a separate model for my application. I could use the same model that retrofit returns to me but what if I want to use another service or data source? Then I would refactor all my application. Often the models under the network are have the same structure with the models for the application. The same question can be applied for the db models and the application models.

So I want to know what is the best practice you use for your application structure.

Comment: That's opinion-based, I think. One good practice is to make application  work as soon as possible and refactor as needed only

Comment: IMO using the same model is not only cleaner, also reduces apk size. Also if the number of APIs used are a lot you'd have write a lot of mapper functions.

Answer (score 0):

A number of practise are there like:

- You can make a common response model that deals with all the common responses that will come every time.
- Then you can make separate response models which will have distinct definition and extend the common base model here.
- Another thing to note is Retrofit 2 gives you the response success status of its own based on the response code so you need not keep a success status in your API, the status code will do the trick.